# Building a Visual Studio extension (VS 2017): Deploying to the experimental instance of VS takes several seconds

Tags: visual-studio-extensions

I am developing a Visual Studio extension (for VS 2017). When the checkbox "Deploy VSIX content to the experimental instance for debugging" is checked, the build takes a ridiculous amount of time (5 to 10 seconds longer than when the checkbox is not checked, on a pretty fast PC).

I have looked inside the diagnostic output of the build and noticed two particular items in the Task Performance Summary, "GetExtensionPath" and "CheckProfileSetup", which are reported as taking 5 seconds each (the latter is used only when I have incremented the version number in the VSIX manifest). Indeed, when I run a build, I see the VSIX file being updated in its directory pretty soon, but the content of the VSIX doesn't appear in the deployment directory (AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_916c0e65Exp\Extensions) until 5 seconds later, and then the build continues, doing apparently nothing, for another 5 seconds.

Is this long delay normal, or how can I prevent it?

Comment: Pretty standard behavior of anti-malware.  Disable it and try again.

Comment: Hans: I did as you suggested but nothing changed.

Answer (score 1):

> Building a Visual Studio extension (VS 2017): Deploying to the experimental instance of VS takes several seconds

As we know, if we are debugging the same version of Visual Studio that we are compiling with, we need to make sure that the following are ticked:

> - **TRUE** Create VSIX Container during build
> - **TRUE** Deploy VSIX content to experimental instance for debugging
> - **FALSE** Copy VSIX content to the following location

When we check the option `Deploy VSIX content to experimental instance for debugging`, there are several tasks would be executed in the output window, like:

```
1>       46 ms  GetExtensionsPath                          1 calls
1>      336 ms  VsixUtil                                   2 calls
1>      413 ms  FindInstalledExtension                     1 calls
1>      964 ms  GetDeploymentPathFromVsixManifest          1 calls
1>      979 ms  EnableExtension                            1 calls
```

VS takes a few seconds to complete those tasks. And if you uncheck this option, those tasks would not be executed, a few seconds of delay will not appear.

Besides, if we check that option, then build the project, there are several file will be generated: `catalog.json`, `extension.vsixmanifest`, `manifest.json` in the extension folder:

```
C:\Users\<Username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_bdfdc7ddExp\Extensions\xxxxx\VSIXProject1\1.0
```

Note: To check this, you could clean the folder `VSIXProject1\1.0` before building the project.

Similarly, if you uncheck that options, those file will not be generated.

So, this delay is normal, we do not have to worry too much about it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: In my case, GetExtensionPath alone takes almost 5 seconds whereas in your example it took only 46 milliseconds (my PC is pretty fast). That's why I asked the question. I was hoping there would be a solution, but it seems that this delay is normal.

Comment: Mine is also a considerable delay. Quite unfortunate for iteration time.
(In my case it takes 30 seconds)